# Heading elements on same line without breaks

Tags: html, css

I have a line of code which is styled using CSS. I wanted it to appear on a single line.

```
<style>
.thumb {
  text-shadow:2px 2px #FF0000;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.click {
font-style: oblique;
}
</style>

<h2 class="click">
    Click a <h3 class="thumb">thumbnail image</h3> to see it enlarged
</h2>
```

I have tried using the below code:

```
<h2 class="click">
    Click a <span style="text-shadow:2px 2px #FF0000">thumbnail image</span> to see it enlarged
</h2>
```

It worked but I wanted to know is there any other way to perform this task?

Answer (score 1):

[`<h3>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements) is a block-level element. If you need to display it on the same line, you should change its default [display type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) to `inline` or `inline-block`.

```
<h2 class="click">
    Click a <h3 class="thumb">thumbnail image</h3> to see it enlarged
</h2>
```

```css
h3.thumb {
  text-shadow:2px 2px #FF0000;
  white-space: nowrap; /* Is this really needed?? */
  display: inline; /* Or inline-block */
}
```

Also note that, [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) is to handle the white space **inside** the element; **Not** around the element itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the display as inline:

```
<style>
    .thumb {
      text-shadow:2px 2px #FF0000;
      white-space: nowrap;
      display: inline;
    }

    .click {
      font-style: oblique;
    }
</style>

<h2 class="click">Click a <h3 class="thumb">thumbnail image</h3> to see it enlarged</h2>
```

However, note that `h2` and `h3` tags are designed for block-level header hierarchies. For something you want to display within the same line, `span` is usually more appropriate.

More info on the purpose of heading tags: http://accessibility.psu.edu/headingshtml